# Convert Parametric equation to cartesian

Tags: parametric, parametrization

I am trying to convert the parametric equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing 3 points:
$\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
3
\end{matrix}\right]
$,
$\left[\begin{matrix}
5\\
1\\
4
\end{matrix}\right]
$,
$\left[\begin{matrix}
6\\
1\\
2
\end{matrix}\right]
$, to a cartesian equation.

The parametric equation I believe is:
$\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
3
\end{matrix}\right] +
s\left[\begin{matrix}
5\\
0\\
1
\end{matrix}\right] +
t\left[\begin{matrix}
6\\
0\\
-1
\end{matrix}\right]
$ with $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$

Following this:

$x = 5s + 6t$

$y = 1$

$z = 3 + s - t$

I am unsure how to proceed, as I am not able to eliminate both $s$ and $t$.

Comment: If you find a normal vector to your plane, you're done....